# learning how to read csv in spyder

Tags: spyder

I have a Covid csv file, which I downloaded, and I would like to see columns of data and pull out as much information as possible, but I'm stuck on the first step.

lines = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("/home/adminp/Downloads/owid-covid-data.csv")

sys.argv[1])
lines.show()

can anybody help me